# datepicker is not working in my modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In index.html i have used this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#btnModal').click(function(){
        $.post('Lab6.html',function(xx){
            $('#tmpModal').html(xx)
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        })
    })
});
```

i've used ajax to call Modal to use it in various pages now date picker is not working in it

This is my Lab6.html

```
<style>          
    </style>  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Select Date" required >
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Date picker is not working here

used jquery script date picker function

Comment: call datepicker after open modal

Comment: lab6.html ? Is this homework?

Comment: Where the jquery datepicker function called??? And read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask